# Sitefinity CMS with High Availability Architecture

Tags: sitefinity

I'm planning to get Sitefinity professional edition for my website that requires HA.

I have 2 x load balanced web servers to serve a website, e.g. www.abc.com.

I'm also planning to host the Sitefinity CMS (as cms.abc.com) in one of the web servers but only allow access from local corporate network (using IP Whitelisting).

2 x database servers (mirrored, active-passive, for disaster recovery).

**May I know if this is achievable in Sitefinity?**

I couldn't find much documentation about this.

The information on this page is confusing to me: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/anton-hristovs-blog/2011/11/10/hosting_recommendations_and_setup

It says that a shared distributed file server / a shared server to host the Sitefinity files and codebase. Why??

I'm new to Sitefinity and used to Sitecore.

Please advise the right way to achieve HA with the servers that I have.

Cheers.

Comment: Sitefinity suggests using a shared file location because it heavily depends on physical configuration files. Changing settings in the backend admin will update physical files on the server from which the changes where made, and not propagate to the other load balanced servers.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported in Sitefinity. Check out this doc section: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/installation-and-administration-guide/load-balancing